# Error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" occurs when trying to access data from a json file, with python

Tags: python, json, string

I am trying to access a part in my json, but it gives me this error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.
Here is my json:

```json
{
    "users": [
        {
            "coins": 50,
            "id": 1234,
            "items": [
                {
                    "collectable1": 3,
                    "collectable2": 2,
                    "collectable3": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is my python:

```py
with open("shoptestjson.json", "r+") as f:
    json_obj = json.loads(f.read())
    users = json_obj["users"]
    for user in users:
        if user["id"] == 1234:
            collectable1 = user["items"]
            print(str(collectable1["collectable1"]))
        else:
            pass
```

It works when I try to just access user["items"], but it doesnt work when I try to access a field in user["items"]. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance if you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `user["items"]`, which you assigned to the local variable `collectable1`, is a list. A list's items need to be accesses with integer indices.

In order to access a field in your example, you would need

```
print(user["items"][0]["collectable1"])
```

The `[0]` is used to access the first and only item of the list that the key `"items"` refers to.

Comment: Thanks for this! I will be accepting this as an answer in 7 minutes. Also this is probably really clear for most people, but I have a hard time understanding things: What do you mean by [0] is used to access the first and only item of the list that the key "items" refers to? Because the way I understand lists, user["items"][0] would just give you the results for collectable1. Sorry if this is obvious and im just not getting it.

Comment: @HoneyPoop Note the `[...]` after `"items": `, wich surrounds the object that contains `collectable1`, etc. This is a list, which currently contains a single item. You could have more items (separated by commas) in this list, but if you only ever need a single item, you could omit `[` and `]` and use what you tried in your question.